# Why square the term $X - \mu$ in the definiton of the variance?

Tags: probability, statistics, definition, variance

Why is is the variance $\operatorname{Var}(X)$  of a random variable $X$ definied to be $\operatorname{E}[(X-\mu)^2]$? My professor said that you want the variance to be positive, but why not go for  $\operatorname{E}[|X-\mu|]$ then? (Just starting on this subject so maybe a stupid question).

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/118

Comment: Because $|x|$ is a much more complicated function than $x^2$ (and the question is not stupid)

Comment: Is your professor a professor of psychology or biology or some other subject in which statistics is used? Any reasonable math professor would not be happy with the answer you say the professor gave you.

Comment: Besides @HagenvonEitzen comment: Because $\mathbb{E}\left[X - \mu\right] = 0$ isn't useful at all.

Comment: That students don't ask this question far more often than they do is an indictment of conventional curricula, whose practical effect is to teach students that mathematics is dogmatic. Students want it to be dogmatic because that's easier if they're just trying to get an impressive grade in a required course, and then consider it unfair to fail to be dogmatic.  And professors who just want to work on research want it to be dogmatic because that's easier and because they think the students are stupid if they just want dogma. The stupidity of$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$both the professors and the students is the same thing and is self-inflicted, for the same reason in both cases. $\qquad$

Comment: @FelixMarin : If I were a student asking about this I would be offended by your comment.

Comment: @Michael Hardy No I think he has a phd in statistics. He just mentioned it shortly in the first lecture and later when I was working on a problem I started wondering about it. And thank you for the quick and elaborate answer (aslo the other people).

Comment: @O.Kro : Perhaps he was impatient and that explains his behavior. Or maybe he thought your classmates would not appreciate a good answer.

Comment: By the way this question has already been asked on an another stackexchange site like the user nobody pointed out: "You might want to take a look at stats.stackexchange.com/q/118" – nobody

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\v}{\operatorname{var}}$Because if $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are independent then $$\v(X_1+\cdots+X_n) = \v(X_1) + \cdots + \v(X_n). \tag 1$$

Nothing like that works for the mean absolute deviation.

Observe that this makes possible: Toss a fair coin $n$ times and ask how many times you get heads. The expected number is $n/2,$ but what is the variance? It's $n/4.$ Simple. But what's the mean absolute deviation? With a fair coin, this has a known answer, but it's complicated, and with a biased coin or with some other distribution it doesn't? So what's the probability that the number of heads is in some range?
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \Pr\left( \frac{(\text{number of heads}) - n/2}{\sqrt{n/4\,\,}} \in A \right) = \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_A e^{-x^2/2} \,dx.
$$
Without this, (a special case of) the central limit theorem, the problem would be much harder and maybe intractable, and we needed to know the variance of the number of heads to do this. Having a measure of dispersion like the variance that satisfies line $(1)$ above makes this possible.

The special case of the central limit theorem that applies to fair coins was discovered in the first half of the 18th century by Abraham de Moivre, except that he computed the normalizing constant numerically without at first knowing that it is $1/\sqrt{2\pi}.$ James Stirling discovered that and communicated it to de Moivre, who I think then included it in a later edition of his book, *The Doctrine of Chances*.

(If I'm not mistaken, the mean absolute deviation of the number of heads in $n$ independent tosses of a fair coin is the same for $n$ as for $n+1,$ if $n$ has a certain parity -- either even or odd, but I don't remember which.)

Comment: Your first sentence is I think a very important reason; but even when you don't have independence the variance of the sum has a very simple form (which you also don't get with other measures of dispersedness)

Answer (score 2):

Variances works somewhat well with sums, as already mentoined in Michael Hardy's answer.

There is more that can be said: variance is (*) the quadratic form associated with an inner product, namely *covariance* , a measure of how different variables vary in relation to each other.

That is, covariance $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) := E((X-EX)(Y-EY))$ is sort of like the dot product $a\cdot b$ of two vectors $a$ and $b$ and then variance $\operatorname{Var}(X) = \operatorname{Cov}(X,X)$ is sort of like the length of a vector $a$ squared $\|a\|^2$. Note that for vectors we have $\|a\cdot a\| = \|a\|^2$.

Now consider the "pythagorean theorem". In the geometry case, we have $\|a+b\|^2 = \|a\|^2 + \|b\|^2$ if $a$ is orthogonal to $b$, i.e. if $a\cdot b = 0$. Accordingly, for variables we have $\operatorname{Var}(X+Y) = \operatorname{Var}(X) + \operatorname{Var}(Y)$ if $X$ and $Y$ are *uncorrolated*
, i.e. if $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) = 0$ (note that independent variables are uncorrolated, but not vice versa).

This motivates why variance should be "quadratic". The *length* in this analogy, as opposed to the square of the length (variance), is called *standard deviation* $\operatorname{sd}(X) = \sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(X)}$.

---

(*) ...if we identify variables that are equal almost surely.